# Vuejs separation and communication between components

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

I made a small vuejs app and I'm a bit confused on how components work.

This is my code so far:

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="loggedIn">
      <nav>
        <router-link to="/a">go to a</router-link>
        <router-link to="/b">go to b</router-link>
      </nav>

      <router-view></router-view>
  </div>

  <div v-else>
    <form v-on:submit.prevent="login" action="">
       <label>
         <input type="text" v-model="name" placeholder="Login" />
       </label>                   

       <label>        
         <input type="password" placeholder="Password" v-model="password" />                    
       </label>         

       <button type="submit">Login</button>        
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
const A = { template: '<div>A</div>' }
const B = { template: '<div>B</div>' }

const routes = [
  { path: '/a', component: A },
  { path: '/b', component: B }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
})

const app = new Vue({
  router,
  data : { 
    loggedIn : false,
    name: '',
    password: ''
  },

  methods: {

    login: function(){
      this.loggedIn = true;
    }

  }

}).$mount('#app')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cbq6tmje/

Notice that the login box is just some html in the index file, but common sense tells me that it should be a separate component.

The problem is that if I make it a component, I have no way of sharing or calling functions from the main app. Like the login() method. How would I do that?

Comment: If such limit reached, I encourage you to use vuex to handle any states.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I've forgotten about prop mutation in my initial answer. I've changed the code to fix that.

Comment: You emit events from the Child component, https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Sending-Messages-to-Parents-with-Events

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make the login box a component. If you plan on reusing an html element i.e. a modal through out your app, then I would consider turning it into a component. If you plan on reusing methods, you would have to covert them into a mixin - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html . You can then extend the mixin to be used in any component you require it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is using localStorage. However, the best way is using vuex (https://vuex.vuejs.org/) which is state management.